# teamcity svn check out - disk space error

Tags: svn, build, teamcity, collabnet, teamcity-9.1

Teamcity build failing with the following error:

> [Updating sources] Failed to build patch for build ... due to error:
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E204900: There is not enough
>   space on the disk

I have checked both Teamcity and SVN have enough disk space.

Teamcity server version is TeamCity Enterprise 9.1.6
SVN server version is CollabNet Subversion v1.4.5
Both are hosted in Windows.

What else could I check? What could be the cause of error?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"VCS Checkout mode" needs to be set to "Automatically on Agent".
also i have added the following checkout rules to VCS root:
'/Master/'=>.